# jQuery Validate plugin and a default input value not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form which has default values set, which should be treated as "empty fields".
I did see another post on this subject, but have not been able to get anything to work so far.
It still only throws the error when the field is empty, but should do so when it has its "default value" as well.

Here is the code with a simple single field form:

---

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<form name="contactInfo" action="##" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="step">
<div style="float:left; width:45%;">
<input type="text" name="email" value="enter your email" tabindex="1" 
onClick="this.select();" required defaultInvalid />
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<!--- form validation to handle non blank default fields --->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function(value, element) 
        {
            switch (element.value) 
            {
                case "enter your email":
                    if (element.name == "email") return false;
                    break;
                default: return true; 
                    break;
            }
        });
     // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#contactInfo").validate(
    {
      rules: 
      {
       email: "required defaultInvalid"
      },
      messages: 
      {
       email: "Please input your email."
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

---

Two issues:

1. it only triggers validation error when empty (instead of when having default value)
2. the custom message I've added does not display.

I've searched stackOverflow and the web for a good hour without any luck finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the default value of the input

```
var default_value = $(this).prop("defaultValue");
```

and compare it to the current value

```
var current_value = $(this).val();
```

EDIT:

You have a simple error: `$("#contactInfo").validate`
Your form does not have an ID contactInfo so you need to add that id to the form tag

```
<form id="contactInfo" name="contactInfo" action="##" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rJVvp/

Comment: how would I apply that to what I've got so far? A complete working example would be grand.

Comment: Excellent. thanks very much. 

Now faced with another issue. The nice looking field highlighting and error message, now appears as times font next to the field.

ie Normal "validation" puts a red border around the problem field, and a message bubble saying "Fill in this field"

its validating on both empty and default value now, but the default error style is not being used.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I mean by "default error style".
I'm wanting to use custom messages, but retain the input field border highlighting and message bubble that says "Please fill out this field"

http://kclsdev.mediathree.net/dev/formFormatted.png

Comment: I think this is a topic for another question, I'm don't know much about jquery validator, sorry.

Comment: His code was not "ok", you missed the botched `rules` inside `.validate()`.

Answer (score 0):

[It works much better when all the errors are fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/PPQw8/)...

---

1)  Form was targeted by `id` but your `form` contained no `id`.  Therefore, the `.validate()` plugin was never initialized on your `form`.

```
<form name="contactInfo" id="contactInfo" ... // <- added an `id`

$("#contactInfo").validate({ ...
```

---

2)  Your rules are mucked up a bit.  This is not valid...

```
rules: { 
    email: "required defaultInvalid"
}
```

should be...

```
rules: {
    email: {
        required: true,
        defaultInvalid: true
    }
}
```

---

3)  The `email` field was a total mess. You cannot create `attributes` that correspond to `rules`.

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="enter your email" tabindex="1" 
onClick="this.select();" required defaultInvalid />
```

You are already defining your `rules` inside of `.validate()`. Otherwise, you'd define them inline using `class="required defaultInvalid"`.

should look like...

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="enter your email" tabindex="1" />
```

I don't know what you're trying to do with `onClick=` so I removed it.  You are using jQuery, so with jQuery, there's never a need for any inline JavaScript event handlers.

---

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/PPQw8/

Read through the documentation:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score -1):

I have custom logic so depending on what button you press you add rules.  You can easily check a value before adding the rules.

```
$('.buttonNextEmail').click(function () {
   if($(".TextBoxEmail").val() != "default string"){
        $(".TextBoxEmail").rules('add', { required: true });
        $(".TextBoxEmailVerify").rules('add', { required: true });
        $(".TextBoxEmailVerify").rules('add', {
            equalToIgnoreCase: '.TextBoxEmail'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: OP did not ask for a whole new solution.  He's asking about how to fix his issue with this plugin.